# DiscardingCookie doesnt delete the cookie from browser in play 2.7?

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I am trying to discard the cookie that was set but none of the following works.

```scala
Ok(views.html.abc())
  .withCookies(Cookie(s.name, s.value, Some(0), s.path, s.domain, s.secure, s.httpOnly, s.sameSite))

Ok(views.html.abc())
  .discardingCookies(DiscardingCookie(s.name))
```

This works locally with localhost but not when its deployed on actual domain.
Could you know why is it so?

Comment: Did you check the HTTP response in a browser Dev tools for instance? Or with a `curl -v`? Can you share with us the response headers, especially the cookie ones.

Comment: yes the cookie in response header is set to age 0 but the domain is different by "." I will try to analyse more on why the dot is removed in response cookie